# Windows Start Menu position

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, start-menu

Is there a way to change position of my Start menu in Windows 7?

When I press the Start button, or Windows button on my keyboard, it opens the start menu with default position bottom left, just above the Windows taskbar.

My Windows taskbar is at the left on the screen so when I open the Start menu, it covers part of my Windows taskbar.

I would like it to open it a little more to the right and up.

Answer (score 0):

## See [Start Orb Mover](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/orb-mover-move-start-button-menu-windows):

[image: Start Orb Mover]

Features of Start Orb Mover:

- Move Start Orb Center or Right\Bottom
- Start Orb Changer
- Show\Hide Taskbar
- Start Menu\Taskbar Properties
- Exit Explorer
- Open Explorer like how the standard Start Menu does
- Restart Explorer
- Open Administrative Command Prompt
- Load on Startup.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesnt solve my problem. It can just move windows start orb. But I want to change position of start menu (that window, which will open after pressing start button).